# angular ui bootstrap modal on different routes

Tags: angularjs, controller, modal-dialog

How would I open routes template in bootstrap modal, without to leave the current page, taking in cosideration the following scenario ?

I have the router

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/views/products.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })

        .when('/product/:articleId', {
            templateUrl: '/views/product-detail.html',
            controller: 'ProductDetailCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
```

Controller

```
angular.module('n2goApp')
        .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location, $cookieStore, api) {
         api.products().then(function(response) {

                $scope.products = response;
                $scope.totalItems = response.total;
                $('#loading').hide();
            })

});
```

produced 1st View which is a list and hyperlinks ro 2nd view and will be opened in modal

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl"><h2><div ng-repeat="product in products"><a href="/product/{{ product.productid}}">{{ product.productname}}</a></h2></div></div>
```

now when user clicks on link will be routed to the 2nd controller, and modal will be produced but leaving the current page // should not leave, behind should stay the current view

```
angular.module('n2goApp')
  .controller('ProductDetailCtrl', function ($scope,$modal, api, $routeParams) {
    var articleID = $routeParams.articleId;
    $scope.edited = api.product(articleID);  
    $modal.open({templateUrl:'/views/product-detail.html'});

  });
```

when user closes modal should see the before visited view

Comment: Your objective is not very clear. Statement about leaving current page is very confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need routes for this. Why don't you simply use an [AngularJS Anchor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref), clicking on which would load the modal with a template. Routes are for switching URLs but you don't want to do that.

If you absolutely have to use routes then you could simulate this by transitioning back to the '/' route once the modal is closed (in the `onClose()` handler or equivalent call `$location.path("/")`). 
Of course this would mean your controller for the home page would get re-executed.

Comment: thanks for the tip with the anchor I will give a try